# Contour-Planar Based Human Pose Estimation

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, contour, pose-estimation

I've been trying to make a contour-based human pose estimation like the one in the center of the image below.

[image: Human Body Models]

I've searched, I couldn't find any code on Github but I found that it can be done with the Active Shape Model (ASM) from this link https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2022/01/a-comprehensive-guide-on-human-pose-estimation/

I am able to access the set of joint positions and draw a skeleton but I don't know how can I do the contour-based pose estimation.

Do you have any suggestions?

Pose Image

[image]

Contour of Human:

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your requirement is similar to morphological dilation. There are libraries (OpenCV, skimage, PIL, etc..) that allow you to do that.

Comment: I assume I should find the contours with the help of the joint points and then draw the rectangles using the mix-max location of the contour.

Comment: @WhiteHatCoder Yes, you can try that. Can you share a sample image?